# Find row name based on specific value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a matrix dataset with values in Excel, where row and column names are identical. I have put all matrix values in a single column, but would now like a formula that returns the matching row name and/ or column name for that value. I have tried VLOOKUP and versions of INDEX and MATCH, but can't get it to work.

Here's an illustration of the data:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup:

Source table range A1:D4

[image]

Values populated in column H for checking.

Formula in cell F2:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$4,MIN(IF($B$2:$D$4=H2,ROW($B$2:$D$4),10^10))),"")`

Formula in cell G2:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$D$1,1,MIN(IF($B$2:$D$4=H2,COLUMN($B$2:$D$4),10^10))),"")`

Depending on your version, you may have to use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to implement these formulas. Output will be like below.

[image]

Comment: A short question: What does 10^10 refer to?

Comment: @MoonS it is just a big number intended to throw an error when there is no match which we show as blank.

Answer (score 0):

You are not looking for a rowname or a columnname, you are looking for the content of the first row or column:

Imagine you want to know the "columnname" of cell "C4", then you just ask for `Cell(3,1)` (3 meaning "C").
Imagine you want to know the "rowname" of cell "C4", then you just ask for `Cell(1,4)`.

Comment: Thanks - although I'm not sure this solves it? Wouldn't this require me to know what cell contains the rowname matching a specific value, and manually enter it? That would be a bit unmanageable for a very large dataset like the one I'm actually using...